# Can I write a template just like the Elsevier LaTeX template?

Tags: journals, copyright, latex, elsevier

A scientific  institute wants me to write a LaTeX template just like the articles which are published on the ScienceDirect website, in other words, the institute wants a template like the following:
[image]

Is it OK to do so with regard to copyright issues?

Comment: Elsevier has its own LaTeX templates; check whether they come with a permissive license. If not, ask Elsevier.

Comment: It is a bit odd the institution wishes that their online stuff looks like a well known publisher?

Comment: @JonCuster: Is it? It may depend on what it is for (the question doesn't even mention the vague "online stuff" you assume as a use case), but picking one of the few commonly used styles of "official publications" seems common enough e.g. for paper-like student essays and similar.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - it might be fine, it might not be, depending on the institution and what they are trying to do, which is not made clear in the question.

Comment: Clearly using Elsevier trademarks (like the logo, and journal identity) is out of the question. I suggest asking your insitution's legal people, or, if available, someone in the library who knows about copyright, how much of the general layout could be adapted.

Answer (score 3):

If you check it on [Elsevier](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) web page, it clearly states that modification of the **manuscript template** is totally ok and they provided the download  [link](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/text_file/0007/56878/ecrc-template.tex).

On the other hand, there are also some other templates that are specific to a journal that is stated to be ethical if you ask the editors' permission.

Check the page out to get more instructions and useful information.

Comment: Does it look like that picture? In my experience, the submission template provided by Elsevier journals does not look at all like the final articles they publish.

Comment: @mehrdadzandigohar: The draft version of elsevier articles doesn't look like the final version at all.